# Group objects with same property - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

i have a simple object

```
var xobj = [
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"View All Users",active: "true" },
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Create users", active: "true" },
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
    { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
    { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
];
```

i am struggling to restructure object based on role_id while grouping permissions for each role_id

[i want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IW7L.png)

What is the efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.reduce` to group the role objects, and use `.find` inside to find the matching `id` object in the accumulator array (if it exists):

```js
const input = [
  { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"View All Users",active: "true" },
  { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Create users", active: "true" },
  { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
  { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
  { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
];
const roles = input.reduce((a, { role_id, permission_name: name, active }) => {
  const foundRole = a.find(({ id }) => id === role_id);
  if (foundRole) foundRole.permissions.push({ name, active });
  else a.push({ id: role_id, permissions: [{ name, active }] });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(roles);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is using an object and accumulate content into its properties

```js
var xobj = [
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"View All Users",active: "true" },
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Create users", active: "true" },
    { role:"Organize Admin", role_id:"id1", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
    { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
    { role:"System Admin", role_id:"id2", permission_name:"Edit users", active: "true" },
];
var groups = {};
xobj.forEach(obj => { 
    if(!groups.hasOwnProperty(obj.role_id)){
        groups[obj.role_id] = [];
    }
    groups[obj.role_id].push(obj);
})
console.log(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

Search for the unique key used to group by. If it doesn't exist, add it and assign an array to it with the current value. Otherwise append the current item to the existing key.

```js
var xobj = [{
    role: "Organize Admin",
    role_id: "id1",
    permission_name: "View All Users",
    active: "true"
  },
  {
    role: "Organize Admin",
    role_id: "id1",
    permission_name: "Create users",
    active: "true"
  },
  {
    role: "Organize Admin",
    role_id: "id1",
    permission_name: "Edit users",
    active: "true"
  },
  {
    role: "System Admin",
    role_id: "id2",
    permission_name: "Edit users",
    active: "true"
  },
  {
    role: "System Admin",
    role_id: "id2",
    permission_name: "Edit users",
    active: "true"
  },
];




const groupedData = xobj.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => Object.keys(y)[0] === x.role_id)
  if (index < 0) {
    acc.push({
      [x.role_id]: [x]
    });
    return acc;
  }
  acc[index] = {
    ...acc[index],
    [x.role_id]: [...acc[index][x.role_id], x]
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(groupedData);
```

Also when having a list/array, name your variable to indicate that it's indeed a list/array instead of **xobj** in your case.